# objectForIndex in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used 1 to 10 number stored in array as:

```
number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];
```

And used `arc4random` in this array as:

```
randomNumber = arc4random() % number.count; //random selected number

NSLog(@"%d",randomNumber);
```

In classname.h file

```
 int randomNumber;
  NSMutableArray *number;
```

How to do `objectforindex` in this array

Comment: `number[randomNumber]`

Comment: You do not have an array of numbers. You have an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
[arrayName indexOfObject:myObject]
```

Check this link [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1417076-indexofobject)

Comment: Can you tell me why you are using NSMutableArray and not simple array here ? I think it should work otherwise

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can simple try:

```
[number indexOfObject:@(randomNumber + 1).stringValue]; //randomNumber + 1 -- because randomNumber is in [0;9] and your strings are in [1;10]
```

For more complicated cases (if you aren't store numbers in strings) then you can use:

```
[arr indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        *stop = YES;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}];
```